# How to check if the value exist in the database table ignoring null in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, orm

I want to ignore null when the query check the value exist in database table in C# using LINQ and Lambda expression.

Below line is checking null as well. When it finds null then ignore it.

```
var nmcExist = db.AspNetUsers.Any(a => a.NMC_Number== model.NMC_Number);
```

Comment: `.Any(a => a.NMC_Number != null && a.NMC_Number == model.NMC_Number);`?

Comment: What does `is checking null as well` mean? And which ORM are you actually using? LINQ is just a query language that the ORM will map to a query. Different ORMs, even different EF versions may produce different SQL queries. In this case the *ONLY* way to check for `null` would be to emit `a.NMC_Number is @p1 or a.NMC_NUMBER IS Null`. EF *doesn't* do that by default, but that behavior can change

Comment: So, **Before** 6.2, the default behavior was to *not* emit `IS NULL`, controlled by [UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontextoptions.usecsharpnullcomparisonbehavior), which is `false` by default. This [changed in 6.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics) and the new default *does* generate `IS NULL`. EF Core doesn't have the option yet. So *which* ORM are you using, which version?

Comment: The EF Core option is [UseRelationalNulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaloptionsextension.userelationalnulls?view=efcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for 2 options:

- If `null`, return `true`

```
.Any(a => a.NMC_Number == null || a.NMC_Number == model.NMC_Number);
```

- If `is not null`, return `true` then check the second condition.

```
.Any(a => a.NMC_Number != null && a.NMC_Number == model.NMC_Number);
```

**Updated**

As @Panagiotis Kanavos 's comment: It really depends on:

- Which ORM are you actually using?
- Which version?

This is simply because, Different ORMs, even different EF versions may produce different SQL queries. Besides, Before EF v6.2, the default behavior was to not emit IS NULL.

Comment: I think he is asking for null to be ignored

Comment: I've updated my answer with 2 options. Please take a look at. Many thanks.

Comment: There may not be any need for this. In EF 6.2, one only needs to set [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to `true`. In EF Core 3.1, it's [UseRelationalNulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaloptionsextension.userelationalnulls?view=efcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes, sir. I've just updated my answer with your advice. Many thanks to @
 Panagiotis Kanavos