# Set All members of a Collection with LINQ to NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, collections

According to this article 
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/07/01/updating-linq.aspx , I want to update collection set one field to NULL for all items

```
//Set all Entity_For = null 
   var relatedPlanToDos = DB.PlanToDos.Where(x => x.EntityFor != null && x.EntityFor.ID == entity.ID);
   relatedPlanToDos.Select(c => { c.EntityFor = null ; return c; }).ToList();
```

This is the syntax Error I get :

> A lambda expression with a statement body can not be converted to an
>   expression tree

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get all value from linq-to-sql first by `.ToList()`

```
var relatedPlanToDos = DB.PlanToDos.Where(x => x.EntityFor != null 
                                             && x.EntityFor.ID == entity.ID).ToList();
```

Then you can do this

```
relatedPlanToDos.Select(c => { c.EntityFor = null ; return c; }).ToList();
```

or

```
relatedPlanToDos.ForEach(c => c.EntityFor = null);
```

**Tips**

1. You should know [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
2. Actually, you no need to check `x.EntityFor != null`, read the following the have a better understanding

[How to check if the value exist in the database table ignoring null in LINQ C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430247/how-to-check-if-the-value-exist-in-the-database-table-ignoring-null-in-linq-c-sh/60430362#60430362)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
var relatedPlanToDos = DB.PlanToDos.Where(x => x.EntityFor != null && x.EntityFor.ID == entity.ID).ToList().ForEach(c => c.EntityFor = null);
```